# file_put_contents and file_get_contents not work other directory

Tags: php, file-io

although file_put_contents and file_get_contents works for `/var/www/html/` they not work for any other directories that have same owner(apache) and chmod(644). What may be the reason? Thanks for helps...

edit:

working code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/osman");
$contents = str_replace("mehmet", '', $contents);
file_put_contents("/var/www/html/osman", $contents);
```

not working code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("/opt/blaris/etc/webfilter/lists/osman");
$contents = str_replace("mehmet", '', $contents);
file_put_contents("/opt/blaris/etc/webfilter/lists/osman", $contents);
```

and as I sad before two file have same owner and chmod...

Comment: Do you get any specific error message when you try to use another directory?

Comment: What about showing some code?

Comment: @Demento no they only return false

Comment: files also have to have the the write permission, not only the directories

Comment: @knittl all of directories and files have write permission and their owner is apache...

Comment: What is your [open_basedir](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) setting?

Comment: I just look at php.ini and it was not set any variable

Comment: The only things I can think of for this are a) the permissions are wrong (you said you already checked that), b) the source and/or target paths don't exist (I'm assuming you checked that too) c) safe mode is in effect, and/or d) open_basedir is in effect.

Comment: If open_basedir is not set, then all files should be reachable. I would try to have a look in phpinfo() instead of php.ini, it could be set elsewhere - phpinfo() will give you the working settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ibrahim

as you mentioned both function (get and put) return false. I am pretty sure this is caused by improper set file/directory permissions (had a same issue some time ago ...).

I solved it by checking the path (in your case "/opt/blaris/etc/webfilter/lists/") if all permissions are set as they should. This also includes read/write permissions for the lists directory itself and ALL directories above.

So make sure all directories in your path are (at least) executable by the apache user (e.g.
    Is /opt executable for apache user?
    Is /opt/blaris executable ...
    Is /opt/blaris/etc executable ...
)

Also make sure the PHP script runs really under the apache user (`<?php echo shell_exec('whoami'); ?>` should give you the information)

If you want to debug it on shell level you may try the following command and see what the output says (in case you have the rights to perform the command on the server ...):

```
sudo -u apache touch /opt/blaris/etc/webfilter/lists/osman
```

Hope that helps ;)